# trigger.io push notification to a specific user

Tags: notifications, push, trigger.io

I am new to trigger.io and possibly going to use Parse for Push Notifications. I need to send specific alerts to a single user automatically when an event happens that affects them specifically. How do I relate their device to their account in my backend system I've built?

I need to send a push notification when a user's service is going to expire is one example, and then I need to send them to a specific url in the app.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually somewhat easy, but you would need to use the parse module and the parse Api

First, to get notifications to a specific user, you would have a user subscribe to a specific channel, this could happen when they login to the app etc, really depends on the architecture of your app.

Now when you send a notification you would only send to a specific channel, this would be the users channel you subscribed them too.

The next step is to use the parse push notification callback to handle what happens when a user clicks on the notification, this is where you would open the url etc.

The Api comes into play when the update action is performed, this would allow you to send the notification from your backend

Comment: fyi here is the link to the Trigger.io API docs on subscribing to Parse channels: https://trigger.io/modules/parse/current/docs/index.html#forgeparsepushsubscribechannel-success-error